# c# Serialize Object throws System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I created my own neural network with the `Neural.NET` library. Since it doesn't have any serialize methods, I downloaded `Newsoft.Json` and `System.Text.Json`. Both throws an exception if I try to serialize it like this:

```
Network _network = new Network(2, new[] { 100, 50 }, 2); //Declare the network object
string myObj = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(_network); //Serialize it
```

Compiler says it doesn't found the method `MathNet.Numerics.Providers.LinearAlgebra.ILinearAlgebraProvider MathNet.Numerics.Control.get_LinearAlgebraProvider()`, which is located in the Provider property of the Network class. Anyway, the Provider is `{get;}` only.

I don't know exactly why the exception is thrown, since it works with other objects, aswell as using MathNet; is declared. Also, I don't know how to fix/workaround this one. I researched and tinkered around for while, but it's like searching a black cat in a dark room for me. Anyone who knows more?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, anything up-to-date, if it helps anyone.

Edit: Well, if I call _network.Provider.ToString() I get the same error. So it's probably everything right with serialization, but I miss something else

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Peter I could solve the problem. The problem was, that the assemblies of `MathNet` which were needed, are not there at runtime. So I reinstalled every Nu-Get dependency in a fresh order. I put especially `MathNet` in the App.config file of my project, and after a restart of Visual Studio everything was compiled as expected.

My advice for everyone who has the same problem: Check if your installed libraries share the same dependencies, and install it in the order they need it, to make sure versions don't get overwritten or stuff.